# How to specify dates on the x-axis to make a bar graph using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plotly

I want to make a bar graph just like the one below. How do I specify the dates on the x-axis using Python 3.5?

[image]

Comment: And none of the gazillion "how to format dates on a matplotlib axis" did answer your question? Your question is too broad, because your input is unclear. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Until then, the matplolib documentation might be of help: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-date-py

Comment: Are you trying to use `matplotlib` or `plotly`?

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to replicate the axis values as much as possible in the below example.

Some properties you may need to know when setting the `x-axis` are:

> **type ( enumerated : "-" | "linear" | "log" | "date" | "category" )** 
>   *default: "-"*  
>  Sets the axis type. By default, plotly attempts to determined the axis type by looking into the data of the traces
>   that referenced the axis in question.
>
> **nticks (integer greater than or equal to 0)** 
>   *default: 0* 
>  Specifies the maximum number of ticks for the particular axis. The actual number of ticks will be chosen
>   automatically to be less than or equal to `nticks`. Has an effect only
>   if `tickmode` is set to "auto".
>
> **tick0 (number or categorical coordinate string)** 
>  Sets the placement of the first tick on this axis. Use with `dtick`. If the
>   axis `type` is "log", then you must take the log of your starting tick
>   (e.g. to set the starting tick to 100, set the `tick0` to 2) except
>   when `dtick`="L" (see `dtick` for more info). If the axis `type` is
>   "date", it should be a date string, like date data. If the axis `type`
>   is "category", it should be a number, using the scale where each
>   category is assigned a serial number from zero in the order it
>   appears.
>
> **tickformat (string)** 
>   *default: ""* 
>  Sets the tick label formatting rule using d3 formatting mini-languages which are very similar to those in Python.
>   For numbers, see:
>   https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_format
>   And for dates see:
>   https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_format
>   We add one item to d3's date formatter: "%{n}f" for fractional seconds
>   with n digits. For example, "2016-10-13 09:15:23.456" with tickformat
>   "%H~%M~%S.%2f" would display "09~15~23.46"
>
> **tickangle (angle)** 
>   *default: auto* 
>  Sets the angle of the tick labels with respect to the horizontal. For example, a `tickangle` of -90 draws the tick
>   labels vertically.

So these properties are set to the below values.

```
type='date',
nticks=40,
tick0=86400000.0,
tickformat="%Y%m%d",
tickangle=-45,
```

Please checkout the below example and let me know if your issue is resolved!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.offline as py_offline
import plotly.graph_objs as go
py_offline.init_notebook_mode()

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv")

trace_high = go.Bar(
                x=df.Date,
                y=df['AAPL.High'],
                name = "AAPL High",
                opacity = 0.8)


data = [trace_high]

layout = dict(
    title = "Manually Set Date Range",
    xaxis = dict(
        type='date',
        nticks=40,
        tick0=86400000.0,
        tickformat="%Y%m%d",
        tickangle=-45,
        range = ['2016-07-01','2016-07-31'])
)

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
py_offline.iplot(fig, filename = "Manually Set Range")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data are in a dataframe accompanied with a date column ('dat') you first need to make that column a date object and then make it an index.

```
df['dat'] = pd.to_datetime(df.['dat'])
df.index = pd['dat']
df['column name'].plot()
```

you can also sort your values before plotting

```
df.sort_value('dat')
```